# How to set a File upload preview?

Tags: angular

I tried to set a code for file upload preview for multiple section,but once i select the file for one section am getting same image preview for all other.. help here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryk3jg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html (my code)

```
selectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.url = event.target.result;

      }
  this.selectedfiles = event.target.files;
  }

}
```

my html code

```
      <div class="form-inline" style="color: black">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <label style ="color: black">Upload ID Front</label>
    <form >
    <div class="form-group" >
        <img [src]="url" height="200"> <br/>
    <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)"  />
  </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
   &nbsp; &nbsp;
   <button (click)="uploadIDfront()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin:0 35%;position:relative;left:-35px;background-color: #3560a5;  /* blue */">Upload</button>
</div>
<br/>

  <div class="form-inline" Style="color: black">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <label style ="color: black">UPload ID Back</label>
    <form >
  <div class="form-group" >
      <img [src]="url" height="200"> <br/>
    <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)" />
  </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
   &nbsp; &nbsp;
   <button (click)="uploadIDback()" class="btn btn-primary"  style="margin:0 35%;position:relative;left:-35px;background-color: #3560a5;  /* blue */">Upload</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
```

am getting same image for both..

Answer (score 0):

Edit: seem like you are reference to same url `variable` and same method `selectFile`. So try to change to different variable and method

Example

In your html add this

```
<img [src]="imageUrl" />

<input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="preview(file.files)"/>
```

then in you component

```
 public imageUrl

    public preview(files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        reader.onload = _event => {
            this.imageUrl = reader.result;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a demo for preview image, you can use it

HTML

```
<input #Image type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"/>
<img *ngIf="imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl" class="image">
```

TS

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  fileToUpload: any;
  imageUrl: any;
  handleFileInput(file: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);

    //Show image preview
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-preview-image-upload?file=src/app/app.component.html

Update

You only update your code with change name event in `onload` event.

You use same event variable with diffent scope.

```
<img #image height="200"> <br/>

 reader.onload = (event1: any, image) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        //this.url = event1.target.result;
        //image.src = event1.target.result;
       event.target.parentElement.children[0].src = event1.target.result;
 }
```

Your code updated

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkiddt

Comment: He just said that `I tried to set a code for file upload preview for multiple section,but once i select the file for one section am getting same image preview for all other` so is not related to his code but his code logic

Comment: Exactly, am getting preview.. but my issue is  am getting same file for all sections(options)...how to solve this...?

Comment: I updated in stackbliz, you need pass the #image for your event

Comment: Getting Error..  ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryk3jg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html                                                                                 this is my code

Comment: update stackbliz with event.target.parentElement.children[0].src = event1.target.result;